# Gutenberg dynamic block render_callback gives null for $post

Tags: block-editor, editor

I am trying to get the current post ID in the `render_callback` function to generate related posts.
However, the `global $post` object gives null.

I use this code for example from [here](https://fernandoclaussen.com/using-render_callback-for-the-edit-function/):

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    register_block_type('fc/related-posts', array(
        'render_callback' => function() {
            global $post;
            var_dump($post); // null
        }
    ));
});
```

It will be fired on `init` but just `$wp` object works others like `$wp_query` or `$post` are null.

Comment: The actual render_callback won't be called until the template is being rendered though will it? Can you get a stack trace to work out exactly when it is being called?

Comment: And it really shouldn't matter but I'd try `var_dump( get_post() );` too, just to make sure there isn't some odd globals scoping problem with lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your block, you need to tell WP that it needs context, either by using `usesContext` in JS/JSON or `uses_context` in PHP.

E.g in PHP:

```php
        'render_callback' => 'render_my_block',
        'uses_context' => [ 'postId' ],
```

This value then takes an array of context identifiers, e.g. `postId` which can then be grabbed in the edit component for rendering, or in PHP at runtime:

```php
function render_my_block( array $attributes, string $content, $block ) : string {
    $post_id = $block->context['postId'];
```

If you do not declare that your block requires the post ID then `$block->context['postId']` will have no value.

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same issue. The workaround I used was to save the current post id as an attribute of the block:

```js
const currentPostId = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    return select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostId();
}, [] );

useEffect( () => {
    if ( currentPostId && currentPostId !== postId ) {
        setAttributes( { postId: currentPostId } );
    }
}, [ currentPostId ] );
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, it will work but for me `.getCurrentPostId()` gives null as well. I could not understand what the problem is!

Comment: Well that is weird. I believe `getCurrentPostId()` is an async function, so you need to make sure you are wrapping it with `useSelect` (or perviously a `withSelect` HOC) in your JS so that you are "subscribing" to any updates of the post ID.

Comment: this won't work, especially if the block is inside a loop type block such as the query block, or in a template. There is no way to know the final post ID from the block editor, it has to be done in PHP when the block is rendered